# Passing out shared pointer to this from destructor

Tags: c++, this, destructor, shared-ptr

I have an object, `BagOfThings`, that stores a set of `Thing`s and a list of `BagOfThingsListener`s, which want to know when a `Thing` is added or removed from the `BagOfThings` they've been added to. Like this:

```
class Thing;
class BagOfThings;

class BagOfThingsListener {
public:
  virtual ~BagOfThingsListener() {}
  virtual void thingAdded(std::shared_ptr<BagOfThings> bag, std::shared_ptr<Thing> thing)=0;
  virtual void thingRemoved(std::shared_ptr<BagOfThings> bag, std::shared_ptr<Thing> thing)=0;
};

class BagOfThings: public enable_shared_from_this<BagOfThings> {
private:
  std::set<std::shared_ptr<Thing>> things;
  std::list<std::shared_ptr<BagOfThingsListener>> listeners;

private:
  BagOfThings() {}

public:
  static std::shared_ptr<BagOfThings> create() {
    return std::shared_ptr<BagOfThings>(new BagOfThings());
  }

  void addThing(std::shared_ptr<Thing> thing) {
    things.insert(thing);
    for (auto it=begin(listeners); it!=end(listeners); ++it) {
      (*it)->thingAdded(shared_from_this(), thing);
    }
  }

  void removeThing(std::shared_ptr<Thing> thing) {
    things.erase(thing);
    for (auto it=begin(listeners); it!=end(listeners); ++it) {
      (*it)->thingRemoved(shared_from_this(), thing);
    }
  }

  ~BagOfThings() {
    for (auto it=begin(things); it!=end(things);) {
      auto currentIt=it++;
      auto &currentThing=*currentIt;
      things.erase(currentIt);
      for (auto it2=begin(listeners); it2!=end(listeners); ++it2) {
        (*it2)->thingRemoved(shared_from_this(), currentThing);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

This works fine except for the destructor, which is invalid as you're not allowed to use `shared_from_this()` when all `shared_ptr`s have been destroyed, which they have by the time the destructor is called. In this case I'm using shared pointers, but it seems to me that handing out the this pointer from the destructor is problematic anyway - someone might store the pointer, for instance. But in this case (wanting to let listeners know on destruction of the removal of all elements), I can't see an obvious nice way of doing it, without removing the pointer to the caller from the listener (i.e. `thingAdded` would become `void thingAdded(std::shared_ptr<Thing>)`).

Any ideas?

Comment: why would you need to implement a destructor for a std::set and a std::list of std::shared_ptr? Let the default destructor do all the magic!

Answer (score 0):

Why does BagOfThingsListener::thingAdded and BagOfThingsListener::thingRemoved need to take a shared_ptr?  Would not a reference/const reference to BagOfThings be enough?  When BagOfThings calls thingAdded or thingRemoved, you know that the this pointer is valid, so a reference will thus also be valid.

Comment: I'm trying to make the interface universally use `shared_ptr` when referring to a `BagOfThings` (hence the named constructor on `BagOfThings`) so that it's clear that these objects are only intended to be referred to by means of a `shared_ptr`. Also, is it good practice to pass the `this` pointer out of a destructor? Having said that, this may well be the best solution.

Comment: My view on that matter is that shared_ptr should not be a golden hammer.  When you use a shared_ptr you signalize that any class may claim ownership of the object, you also give up control on when an object owned by the shared_ptr is deleted.  I would also say that passing the this pointer out of a destructor is okay, as long as you don't give the impression that the object may be owned for longer than the function call, *and* your this pointer is not a virtual object.  Calling virtual functions on a class that is being created or destroyed is undefined behavior.